# Playing around with the Nested Interval Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The Nested Interval Theorem says that:

> If $(I_n)$ is a sequence of **closed** and **bounded** non-empty intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ with $I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq ...$ then $$\bigcap\limits_{i= 1}^{\infty} I_i \neq \varnothing$$
> Moreover, if $\text{len}(I_n) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, then $\displaystyle \bigcap\limits_{i= 1}^{\infty} I_i$ is a singleton.

I'm curious about a few questions:

---

If $(I_n)$ is a sequence of **closed** non-empty intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ with $I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq ...$, and $\text{len}(I_n) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Also, $$\bigcap\limits_{i= 1}^{\infty} I_i \neq \varnothing$$

**Does this imply that $I_n$ is bounded $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$**? What if we remove the condition that $\text{len}(I_n) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$?

If, in addition to the above, we say that $$\bigcap\limits_{i= 1}^{\infty} I_i = \{x\}$$ what more can we deduce? I suppose we can say that any sequence $x_n\in I_n, \forall n$ is such that $\lim x_n = x$.

---

If $(I_n)$ is a sequence of **bounded** non-empty intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ with $I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq ...$, and $\text{len}(I_n) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Also, $$\bigcap\limits_{i= 1}^{\infty} I_i \neq \varnothing$$

**Does this imply that $I_n$ is closed $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$**? What if we remove the condition that $\text{len}(I_n) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$?

If, in addition to the above, we say that $$\bigcap\limits_{i= 1}^{\infty} I_i = \{x\}$$ what more can we deduce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first qestion: "Does this imply that $_$ is bounded?", no.
Suppose that it is the case that we have some sequence of closed intervals such that $I_1\supset I_2...,$ where len$(I_n)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ and,
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}{I_n}\neq\emptyset$$
If this would imply that $I_n$ is bounded $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, the we could just construct some closed unbounded interval $I_0$ such that $I_0\supset I_1$. Then all the previous assumtions holds for the sequence of intervals $(J_n)$, where $J_n=I_{n-1}$ but $(J_n)$ is not bounded for all natural numbers.

The same logic can be applied to your question if it implies that the intervals are closed.

To your other question about a sequence $x_n\in I_n$. If len$(I_n)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ Then yes, such a sequence would converge to $x$.

To show this, let $\varepsilon$ be given, then there is some $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\geq N$ the len$(I_n)<\varepsilon$. Since $x,x_n\in I_n \implies |x-x_n|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: what is an example of a closed unbounded interval

Comment: @john The whole real line and $[0, \infty)$ are both closed and unbounded.